# postgres select-statement with extract takey very long

Tags: postgresql

I have a very large table with a column with epoch-time, which is part of the primary key.
This statement

```
select
    count("time")
from
    public.timeseriesfloat
where
    "time" < extract(EPOCH from TIMESTAMP with TIME zone '2021-01-10')  
    and "time" > extract(EPOCH from TIMESTAMP with TIME zone '2021-01-09');
```

takes extremely long.

If i try the statement like this

```
 SELECT count("time")
     FROM public.timeseriesfloat
     where "time" <  1610233200 and "time" > 1610146800;
```

it is real fast.

Maybe it is because the extract calculates the date-to-epoch-conversion for every row. What can i do to change this behavior?

Comment: Which version of postgresql? Modern versions should evaluate extract only once. Your method of computing unix timestamp outside of sql will work too. However, consider storing timestamps in postgresql native type

Comment: Store dates and timestamps properly typed. Do not use epoch, see [Epoch Maina](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/).  It was great for Unix in the 1970s - but not so much anymore.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.